# Cannot assign operator on python3

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I am learning python and trying make my code in function.

```
## set total sticks number
stick_left = 20
## Given hints, this for statement shows sticks
for _ in range(5): print('|  '*stick_left)
## this condition lasts until stick = 0
while stick_left>0:
    ## first player
    first_player=input('Player1: please pick sticks up to 3 ')
    if first_player>3 or first_player<0:
        print('Please pick between 1-3 stick(s)')
    else:
        stick_left-=first_player
        if stick_left<=0:
            print ('Player1 lost')
            break
        else:
            print('There is %d stick(s) left' %stick_left) ## print how many sticks left
            for _ in range(5): print('|  ' * stick_left)
    ## second player
    second_player = input('Player2: Please pick sticks up to 3 ')
    if second_player > 3 or second_player < 0:
        print('Please pick between 1-3 stick(s)')
    else:
        stick_left -= second_player
        if stick_left <= 0:
            print ('Player2 lost')
            break
        else:
            print('There is %d stick(s) left' % stick_left)
            for _ in range(5): print('|  ' * stick_left)
```

and this is my code includes function

```
player =0
def player():
    for i in 2:
        player%d %i= input('Player %d:  Please pick sticks up to 3' %i)
        if player >3 or player <0:
            print('Please pick between 1-3 stick(s)')
```

On line 4, I want to make it print player1 player2, but I just notice that I cannot assign operator like that.
I tried `player_%d %i` but no luck. Can anybody give me advice please?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't have a variable called `player` and a function with the same name

Comment: @ForceBru You can, it would just redefine the variable. So `player` inside the function would refer to the function, not `0`.

Comment: @TuomasLaakkonen, so this will result in a mess and do something the OP doesn't want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Comment: Use a list here; in the general case see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define variable names on the fly like this. Use a dictionary.

```
players = {}
def player():
    for i in range(2):
        players[i] = input("Player %d: Please pick sticks up to 3" % (i,))
        # etc
```

Comment: could as well use a `list` (though 0-indexed).

Comment: In this case, sure, although it doesn't look to me like there is even a *need* for a separate variable for each player.

Answer (score -1):

exec() function will work for you. Please refer below code.

```
player =0
def player():
    for i in range(1,3):
        exec("player%d = input('Player%d =  Please pick sticks up to 3 ')" %(i,i))
player()
```

Following is the o/p.

> Player1 =  Please pick sticks up to 3 1
>
> Player2 =  Please pick sticks up to 3 2

Comment: While this would work, please *please* do not recommend exec to a new programmer. There is a ridiculous amount of foot-shooting possible here.

Comment: And this *won't* actually work in Python 3 (although it would have in Python 2).  If you add `print(player1)` after the loop, it'll work in Py2 and give you a NameError in Py3.

Comment: @PShiw: as I said, try adding `print(player1)` after the loop.  That will fail in Python 3.4 with `NameError: name 'player1' is not defined` even though it will succeed in Python 2.7, because of changes in how `exec` behaves.